# MS Word mail merge function result, not function formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, worksheet-function, mail-merge

I am doing mail merge in MS Word 2010 to automatically fill some forms using a MS Excel 2010 spreadsheet. Values result from an Excel function. Mail merging works, but instead of printing the function result, it prints the formula itself. Is there a solution to avoid this problem, without using workarounds (such as copy-paste values in the Excel spreadsheet)?

Comment: Are the results appearing correct in Excel? Do you get the same result if you do the mail merge if Excel is open / closed during it?

Comment: Great, you found the solution. Keeping the Excel file closed (I didn't even notice it was open...). Add it as answer, I'll flag it as correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be differences how Word receives the information from the workbook depending whether it is open in Excel at the time of read.

Try closing Excel when you generate the mail merge.